Is creating a React UI library with a CSS re-implementation of a GNU LGPLv2.1 licensed C implementation a violation of the GPL?
I'm currently in the process of developing a new React UI library, drawing inspiration from the Adwaita design system. There is a C language implementation of a library called libadwaita. However, this C implementation is licensed under GNU LGPLv2.1.
My intention is to utilize the CSS portion of that project implementation to re-implement it in React.js, and I plan to release this CSS code under the MIT license.

Would this be considered a violation of the GPL?

Furthermore, if I decide to release the CSS portion under the same GNU LGPLv2.1 license as the C implementation, would this require users of my library to open-source their applications under the GPL as well?



In most cases "reimplementing" means you are reading source code and then rewriting that code in a different language or environment. If that's what you mean, could you read this https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/licence-of-open-source-software-re-implementation
Q2 - When you say "release the CSS part" do you mean release the portion of code that handles CSS, or are you talking about releasing certain CSS styling files only?

Also note that this project says that it is LGPLv2.1 "+" and it's mentioned that you can use v2.1 or later. It means technically your options are to release your derived code as either: LGPLv2.1+ as well (retaining the upgrade option), as LGPLv2.1 (without upgrade option) or to release your code as LGPLv3, however, if you do that it might not be good, because then the original project technically couldn't take any of the innovations in your fork back into their version without your specific permission.

@Brandin Technically you can choose either "LGPL v3" or "LGPL v3+" (v3 or any later version) as well. There is no v4 yet but there could be eventually.

@Brandin I meant release the portion of code that handles CSS. It is okay I can release the project under same GPL license. But can someone use my library in their proprietary project or they need to release it under GPL license

If you use rewrite existing code or portions of existing code (libadwaita, written in C, or portions thereof) into a different language, or for a different environment, etc., then this is the definition of a derivative work, so you'll need to respect the same open-source license – LGPLv2.1+ in this case (i.e. the LGPL v2.1 or “at your option” a later version).
Fortunately, the LGPL explicitly allows using the code in larger projects of any license; it is definitely not a violation to use the code in a proprietary application, for example, and it would not require open-sourcing the whole application, that’s for sure.
However, since the LGPL component in this case will be JavaScript code (React.js), then it might raise some questions about what the practical requirements are to use your component in some other web application. This is because whoever visits the page will get a copy of that JavaScript code, and if that code is is LGPL licensed, then a strict reading of the LGPL implies that she ought to receive the "Corresponding Source" of that JavaScript component as well.
One way this is done sometimes is to provide a link in an appropriate place on the web page (e.g. Copyrights, Legal, Impressum, or some page with a name like that), and that to ensure the source code to the ReactJS component can be retrieved from such a page.
This isn't so hard in and of itself, but if there is a webdev out there that just wants to use your component in an existing web application (an application which is probably not itself open-sourced), then your library might now seem like it's more trouble than it's worth – at minimum he’ll have extra work to do in the page content itself, in order to add a notice and/or link to download Corresponding Source to this React.js component. Additionally, webdevs themselves are often not the publishers of the page content itself, so it might be difficult to comply with the LGPL requirement even if he wants to – I would not like to be the webdev trying to explain to the publishers why they must now host a page where "Corresponding Source" can be downloaded for other programmers, especially if this application is part of a closed-source web application.
A technical workaround to this requirement might be to disable any sort of JavaScript 'compilation', 'minification' or any sort of comment-stripping, name-mangling or abbreviation that normally happens in the React.js compilation process -- the idea is ensure that what users receive in their browsers when they click 'View Source' and go to look at the code, that what they see in the browser will already be the "Corresponding Source" of that component. If you ensure this is done, then interested users (who are skilled enough to know how to use the "View Source" command) would already be able to download the "Corresponding Source" simply by using their web browser. Downloading the source to the JavaScript in this way would certainly not be the optimal developer experience, but it’s still possible to do so, and the code is all there, so it would still seem to satisfy the LGPL Corresponding Source requirement in my opinion.
Another variation of the above workaround would be place a special comment somewhere in the code, a comment which is somehow protected from being "minified" or "stripped out", which would inform developers (when they click "View Source") that the code is LGPLv2.1 and to offer them via a hyperlink to download the Corresponding Source (i.e. to download the original React.js component before it's compiled/minified/etc.). If you want to do it this way, then maybe you could ask in a React.js-specific forum if there's a way to instruct the compilation system to preserve the comment in your compiled version.
Finally, another option is to try contacting the maintainer of the component to see if you can license your version under a different (open-source) license. Instructions for doing this are in the LGPL itself, section 14:


If you wish to incorporate parts of the Library into other free
programs whose distribution conditions are incompatible with these,
write to the author to ask for permission.  For software which is
copyrighted by the Free Software Foundation, write to the Free
Software Foundation; we sometimes make exceptions for this.  Our
decision will be guided by the two goals of preserving the free status
of all derivatives of our free software and of promoting the sharing
and reuse of software generally.


See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200783/can-i-use-a-lgpl-licensed-library-for-my-web-project
